# using intents to start over the activity

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent i= new Intent( SetTest.this, SetTest.this);// compile error there
i.putExtra("question_number", questionNumber++);
startActivity(i);
```

I want to post the data to the same activity.. . Here is my intent filter in the mainfest file:

```
      <activity android:name="SetTest">
         <intent-filter android:label="@string/setQuestion">
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I dont understand why do I get the compile error?!?

I get compile error, with this too:

```
 Context context=getApplicationContext();
```

Intent i= new Intent(context, SetTest.this);

Comment: And next reaction would be "what error message did I get?" Please post  the message. And generally what is the purpose of calling its own activity?

Comment: I want the same activity to generate so the user will fill the data. It is like a kind of multiform..with the exact fields.  I thought to call oncreate(bundle)...but I am not sure if it is a better decision. Error message,says that I need to remove constructor to Intent(). IT is a compile error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS the other answers say :

```
Intent i= new Intent( SetTest.this, SetTest.Class);
i.putExtra("question_number", questionNumber++);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

As you're loading the same activity, you might want finish your current activity to avoid problem in your navigation tree

Comment: thanks for the question. I have another question.. I can see that android uses many events with each widget..Is there a way to split the code into files.. I have over 500 lines in one page, and it is a bit difficult to navigate..

Comment: hum, it's a bit difficult to answer directly, but of course there are way to alight your code in the activity. First, your can create a main activity, and make your current activity a subclass of the new class. You can also Create class to handle Data manipulation, etc ... you're free to imagine as much as you want

Comment: are you sure that the intent posts to itself, cause I cant see the oncreate method starting in the logcat..? may be it adds the activity to the activity stack... But I see nothing in the logcat..and the variable that I pass remain the same.. questionNumber=i.getIntExtra("question_number", questionNumber); when I retrieve it

Comment: i.putExtra("question_number", questionNumber++); and are you sure your previous question number is good, and after ++ is OK ?

Answer (score 1):

Save off the context of the activity to a member varaible, and then use the saved context in your intent creation.

```
private Context _context;

Constructor...
{
_context = this;
}
```

Then in the button callback:

```
Intent i= new Intent( _context, newDesiredClass.class);
```

Comment: whats the difference, between your code to this:  Context context=getApplicationContext();

Comment: The difference is in the second arg, ".class" and not a reference to your actual context ".this"

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
Intent i= new Intent( SetTest.this, SetTest.Class);
```

Hope this will work

Comment: yeah, it worked.. could you explain why? why cant I use : SetTest.this, SetTest.this instead of SetTest.this, SetTest.class