# Application didn't launch when I create a Button in java

Tags: android

I've a strange problem. I explain after this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    // final Button buttonAlpha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Alphabet);

}
```

Look you see, I put in comments the buttonAlpha and the launching of application works perfectly but when I remove the comments, my app didn't launching and I've no idea why. If somebody have/had the same problem, can I help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put

```
final Button buttonAlpha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Alphabet);
```

inside a method or else it will try to run it before running `onCreate()`, hence before `setContentView()`

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button buttonAlpha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Alphabet);
  }
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! But if I want to create a new view, How can I do this ? I create the variable buttonAlpha for to have a new view when I cliked on this button.

Comment: I don't understand...You want to create some `View` in this `Activity` like a `TextView` or you want to start a new `Activity`?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanations that I gave. When the user clicks on the button, I want to start a ne Activity.

Comment: then you need to use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). [Here is a good example of using them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330858/using-intents-to-start-over-the-activity)

Comment: Okey I see it but I put the Intent directly after the definition of buttonAlpha or there is a better way to do this ?

Comment: In an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Comment: You need to start [here in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) if you have these kinds of questions. Go through the beginning and you will get a good grasp of getting started